# How to render the file returned by ajax

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

I managed to make ajax working on my website. It returns a php file. The problem is that, it displays the php file as plain text Instead i need to render the html tags and display..

Comment: what is your existing code to display it? HTML is plain text also. what exactly do you mean by `plain text`?

Comment: i have <img> tags in my php file. So the final output i get is just the text <img> and not the images. am i clear now??

Comment: just assign the text (with tags) to a html elements `innerHTML` property.

Comment: oh my bad! Small spelling mistake on my code. Anyw thanks a lot.

Comment: If you shared code in the first place, someone would just point it out before you start nailbitting :) always share code in question if possible.

Answer (score 3):

Look at [this](http://www.degraeve.com/reference/simple-ajax-example.php) page.

After you get the response, you need to assign it to `innerHTML` property of your target element.

In your web page, have a div:

```
<div id="result"></div>
```

Now, when you get the response of ajax (in a javascript method), do this

```
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = the_string_returned_by_ajax;
```

The link provided has working sample.

---

If you **still** keep seeing html tags rather than rendered html by browser, it is likely that your serverside script for ajax is returning escaped string, i.e. it may be returning `&lt;` instead of `<` and so on.